# Attachments are missing in outlook 2010

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2010

I wrote some VBA macro to download all the attachments of my outlook.I used the following code to achieve that:

```
Public Sub SaveAttachments()
  Dim objOL As Outlook.Application
  Dim objMsg As Outlook.MailItem
  Dim objAttachments As Outlook.Attachments
  Dim objSelection As Outlook.Selection
  Dim i As Long
  Dim lngCount As Long
  Dim strFile As String
  Dim strFolderpath As String
  Dim strDeletedFiles As String
  strFolderpath = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders(16)
  On Error Resume Next
  Set objOL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
  Set objSelection = objOL.ActiveExplorer.Selection
  strFolderpath = strFolderpath & "\Attachments\"
  For Each objMsg In objSelection
    Set objAttachments = objMsg.Attachments
    lngCount = objAttachments.Count
    strDeletedFiles = ""
    If lngCount > 0 Then
      For i = lngCount To 1 Step -1
        strFile = objAttachments.Item(i).FileName
        strFile = strFolderpath & strFile
        objAttachments.Item(i).SaveAsFile strFile
        objAttachments.Item(i).Delete
        If objMsg.BodyFormat <> olFormatHTML Then
          strDeletedFiles = strDeletedFiles & vbCrLf & "<file://" & strFile _
            & ">"
        Else
          strDeletedFiles = strDeletedFiles & "<br>" & "<a href='file://" _
            & strFile & "'>" & strFile & "</a>"
        End If
      Next i
      If objMsg.BodyFormat <> olFormatHTML Then
        objMsg.Body = vbCrLf & "The file(s) were saved to " & strDeletedFiles _
          & vbCrLf & objMsg.Body
      Else
        objMsg.HTMLBody = "<p>" & "The file(s) were saved to " _
          & strDeletedFiles & "</p>" & objMsg.HTMLBody
      End If
      objMsg.Save
    End If
  Next
  ExitSub:
  Set objAttachments = Nothing
  Set objMsg = Nothing
  Set objSelection = Nothing
  Set objOL = Nothing
End Sub
```

It was run successfully.

But I could not find that folder in my system. I was trying to open in mail at least, but it was saying that the attachment has been saved to `C:\xxxx.....` folder which actually does not exist in my system. I need those attachments and they are very important.

Is there any way to restore those mail attachments. (I guess, attachments have been deleted from the server itself, since there was a statement in mycode `objAttachments.Item(i).Delete`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely your procedure encountered an error when trying to save the attachments to a non-existent folder, since the code doesn't bother checking if saving the attachment is successful or if the folder exists in the first place. However, the error was suppressed by the `On Error Resume Next`, so the code continued to deleting the attachments, even though they hadn't been saved. Unless you have a backup, the attachments are probably lost.

**NEVER** use `On Error Resume Next` unless you know **exactly** what you're doing **and** have sensible error-handling code in place.